# Why isn't my custom post type archive URL translating?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, localization

I've god a 'wine' custom post type, created with rewriting options:

```
'rewrite' => array(
  'slug' => __('vini', 'fdr'),
  'with_front' => false,
  'pages' => false
),
```

So the slug should translate. I've got an `en-GB.po/mo` where I'm translating 'vini' to 'wines'.

Though, the URL generated under translations are not translated:

- original: `[base url]/vini/teroldego-morei/`
- translated: `[base url]/en/vini/teroldego-morei/`

What I would like (and I guess, should be): `[base url]/en/wines/teroldego-morei/`

So what? The [official docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) say 'Should be translatable'.
Well, it is, but it seems the whole thing doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that you get the right string from your po/mo files? I would echo that somewhere to check. Just an idea, may you are sure about it.

Comment: Also, flush rewrite rules every time you change something regarding them. Go to Settings -> Permalinks and click Save without changing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE 1:

I haven't find a solution yet (other than using Polylang Pro). But I must add that my original question was partially wrong, since the `rewrite` option is for the single page url, not the archive one.

Custom post type archive has its own slug and it's the `has_archive` option (can be boolean or string). So basically can be something like this:

```
'has_archive' => __('products','mytxtdomain')
```

Though, just as the rewrite url, it doesn't work, and probably the answer below is still valid.

---

The answer is: it's not possible.

Falks or the Polylang Pro crew explained me the reason why:

If you flush your rewrite rules while the locale is Italian, your slug is evaluated to 'vini'. If you flush them while the locale is English, the slug is evaluated to 'wine'. So, in the first case, the rewrite rule pattern is:

vini/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$

and in the second case, it is

wine/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$

But you never have both at the same time. So only one is working.